# Convolution and catastrophic codes

Tags: coding-theory

i'm reading the article of Massey and Sain ([here](http://www.isiweb.ee.ethz.ch/archive/massey_pub/pdf/BI413.pdf)) and i cannot unserstand - what is "foreforward inversion"?

I mean

There is a description of circles in convolutional codes and a little bit description about catastrophic codes (i mean, codes that makes an infinite amount of errors on decoding if there was a couple of errors in channel).

Who can explain, what is "foreforward inversion", and which delay is meant?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. i interested in this theme because i want to understand the proof of Theorem 1 in that article, no more.

Comment: As it stands, your question is not stand alone. Someone would have to go fetch the paper you link to in order to understand it. This is no good as the paper could be removed. Please make your question more stand alone.

Comment: @mikeazo ehm... i misunderstand Your request... this article in free access, why it could be removed?

Comment: you mean to tell me you've never seen a link change? Or a website disappear? either way a good question should be self containing.

Comment: Also, it is unclear how the question directly relates to cryptography. Could you explain that too?

Comment: @mikeazo well... by now i don't have possibility to do what You ask. about second question - i think that error-correcting codes are the part of cryptography. well, yes, it is another theme, but... well, ok, i think that some questions about "coding" at all can be done in cryptography =)